# How can I make a counter variable in jQuery that changes the images when the user clicks on the right and and left arrow buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to figure out how to increment and decrement the counter variable so that when the user clicks on the right arrow button the image will go to the second image(#image2) then the third image(#image3) and when the user clicks on the left arrow button the image will go back to the previous image. I am new to jQuery and new to using counters.

```js
$(document).ready(function()  { 
      let counter = 1;
     $("#image2").hide();
     $("#image3").hide();

     $("body").on('click',"#image2-thumbnail",function() {
      currentimage = "#image2" + counter;  
      counter++ ;
      $(currentimage).hide();  
        $("#image1").slideUp('slow');
        $("#image3").slideUp('slow');
        $("#image2").slideDown('slow');    
     });   
     $("body").on('click',"#image3-thumbnail",function() {
       currentimage = "#image2" + counter;  
       counter++ ;
      $(currentimage).hide();  
        $("#image2").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#image1").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#image3").fadeIn(1000);    
     }); 
     $("body").on('click',"#image1-thumbnail",function() {
       currentimage = "#image2" + counter;  
       counter++ ;
      $(currentimage).hide();  
        $("#image3").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#image2").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#image1").fadeIn(1000);    
     }); 
    $("#rightArrow").click(function() {
       currentimage = "#image2" + counter;  
       counter++ ;
      $(currentimage).hide();  
    }
    )

      $("#lefttArrow").click(function() {
       currentimage = "#image2" + counter;  
       counter++ ;
      $(currentimage).hide();  
    }
    )
    
    });
```

```css
body {
    background-color: lightpink;
}

#header {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: yellow;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
}

#slideshow {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#image1 {
    border-radius: 100px;
}

#image2 {
    border-radius: 100px;
}

#image3 {
    border-radius: 100px;
}

#image1-thumbnail {
    border-radius: 120px;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

#image2-thumbnail {
    border-radius: 120px;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

#image3-thumbnail {
    border-radius: 120px;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

#thumbnails {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 100%;
    gap: 10px;
}

button {
    background-color: purple;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script> 
    <title>jQuery</title>
</head>
<body background="candy-background.jpg">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Candy</h1>
        </div>
    <div id="slideshow">
        <img id="image1" 
        src="https://wearenotmartha.com/wp-content/uploads/DIY-Rock-Candy-Featured.jpg" width="400px">
        <img id="image2" 
        src="https://www.speachfamilycandy.com/contents/media/l_smallspicegumdrops.jpg" width="400px">
        <img id="image3" src="https://st4.depositphotos.com/4585465/20188/i/1600/depositphotos_201883238-stock-photo-colorful-candies-dessert-background.jpg" width="400px">
    </div>
    <div id="thumbnails">
            <button id="leftArrow"> < </button>
            <img id="image1-thumbnail" 
            src="https://wearenotmartha.com/wp-content/uploads/DIY-Rock-Candy-Featured.jpg" width="100px">
            <img id="image2-thumbnail" 
        src="https://www.speachfamilycandy.com/contents/media/l_smallspicegumdrops.jpg" width="100px">
            <img id="image3-thumbnail" src="https://st4.depositphotos.com/4585465/20188/i/1600/depositphotos_201883238-stock-photo-colorful-candies-dessert-background.jpg" width="100px">
            <button id="rightArrow"> > </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A little unclear why you need a Counter or an Index. If all of them are in a slide show then you just have to move the `left` one direction or the other.

Comment: Our professor told us we have to do it that way. We are learning jquery and she says to put a counter on it. Is there another way to do it in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#thumbnails").on('click', "img", function() {
    var sel = $(this).index();
    $("#slideshow img").fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $("#slideshow > img").eq(sel).fadeIn();
    });
  });

  $("#thumbnails").on("click", "button", function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var current = $("#slideshow > img:visible");
    var prev, next;

    if (current.index() != 0) {
      prev = $("#slideshow > img:last");
    } else {
      prev = current.prev("img");
    }

    if (current.index() == $("#slideshow > img").length - 1) {
      next = $("#slideshow > img:first");
    } else {
      next = current.next("img");
    }

    current.fadeOut(1000, function() {
      if (self.attr("id") == "leftArrow") {
        prev.fadeIn();
      } else {
        next.fadeIn();
      }
    });
  });

  $("#slideshow > img").hide(function() {
    $("#slideshow > img:eq(0)").show();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightpink;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: yellow;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
}

#slideshow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#image1 {
  border-radius: 100px;
}

#image2 {
  border-radius: 100px;
}

#image3 {
  border-radius: 100px;
}

#image1-thumbnail {
  border-radius: 120px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#image2-thumbnail {
  border-radius: 120px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#image3-thumbnail {
  border-radius: 120px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#thumbnails {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  gap: 10px;
}

button {
  background-color: purple;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <h1>Candy</h1>
</div>
<div id="slideshow">
  <img id="image1" src="https://wearenotmartha.com/wp-content/uploads/DIY-Rock-Candy-Featured.jpg" width="400px">
  <img id="image2" src="https://www.speachfamilycandy.com/contents/media/l_smallspicegumdrops.jpg" width="400px">
  <img id="image3" src="https://st4.depositphotos.com/4585465/20188/i/1600/depositphotos_201883238-stock-photo-colorful-candies-dessert-background.jpg" width="400px">
</div>
<div id="thumbnails">
  <button id="leftArrow"> &lt; </button>
  <div>
    <img id="image1-thumbnail" src="https://wearenotmartha.com/wp-content/uploads/DIY-Rock-Candy-Featured.jpg" width="100px">
    <img id="image2-thumbnail" src="https://www.speachfamilycandy.com/contents/media/l_smallspicegumdrops.jpg" width="100px">
    <img id="image3-thumbnail" src="https://st4.depositphotos.com/4585465/20188/i/1600/depositphotos_201883238-stock-photo-colorful-candies-dessert-background.jpg" width="100px">
  </div>
  <button id="rightArrow"> &gt; </button>
</div>
```

An index is really only needed if you have a large data set, like an Array of Image paths. It is then easier to have an index so that you can move through the array better.

With a list of Image Elements, where only one is visible, this in essence become your Index. For Left / Right Arrows, hide your current element, and you can use `.prev()` and `.next()` to show the next elements. For direct clicks, they are in the same order, so easy to get the `.index()` of the thumbnail, hide all others, and reveal that specific Image.

If you MUST use a Counter, you can still do this with the same code.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var counter = 0;

  function showImage(index) {
    $("#slideshow > img").fadeOut(1000, function() {
      console.log("Showing Img " + index);
      $("#slideshow > img").eq(index).show();
    });
  }

  $("#thumbnails").on("click", "button", function(event) {
    var self = $(this);
    console.log("Button Click");
    if (self.is("#leftArrow")) {
      counter--;
      if (counter < 0) {
        counter = $("#slideshow > img").length - 1;
      }
    } else {
      counter++;
      if (counter == $("#slideshow > img").length) {
        counter = 0;
      }
    }
    showImage(counter);
    return false;
  });
  
  $("#thumbnails").on("click", "img", function(event) {
    var self = $(this);
    console.log("Img Click");
    counter = self.index();
    showImage(counter);
    return false;
  });

  showImage(counter);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightpink;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: yellow;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
}

#slideshow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#image1 {
  border-radius: 100px;
}

#image2 {
  border-radius: 100px;
}

#image3 {
  border-radius: 100px;
}

#image1-thumbnail {
  border-radius: 120px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#image2-thumbnail {
  border-radius: 120px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#image3-thumbnail {
  border-radius: 120px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#thumbnails {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  gap: 10px;
}

button {
  background-color: purple;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <h1>Candy</h1>
</div>
<div id="slideshow">
  <img id="image1" src="https://wearenotmartha.com/wp-content/uploads/DIY-Rock-Candy-Featured.jpg" width="400px">
  <img id="image2" src="https://www.speachfamilycandy.com/contents/media/l_smallspicegumdrops.jpg" width="400px">
  <img id="image3" src="https://st4.depositphotos.com/4585465/20188/i/1600/depositphotos_201883238-stock-photo-colorful-candies-dessert-background.jpg" width="400px">
</div>
<div id="thumbnails">
  <button id="leftArrow"> &lt; </button>
  <div>
    <img id="image1-thumbnail" src="https://wearenotmartha.com/wp-content/uploads/DIY-Rock-Candy-Featured.jpg" width="100px">
    <img id="image2-thumbnail" src="https://www.speachfamilycandy.com/contents/media/l_smallspicegumdrops.jpg" width="100px">
    <img id="image3-thumbnail" src="https://st4.depositphotos.com/4585465/20188/i/1600/depositphotos_201883238-stock-photo-colorful-candies-dessert-background.jpg" width="100px">
  </div>
  <button id="rightArrow"> &gt; </button>
</div>
```

Working with original code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let counter = 1;
  $("#image2").hide();
  $("#image3").hide();

  $("body").on('click', "#image2-thumbnail", function() {
    currentimage = "#image" + counter;
    counter = 2;
    $(currentimage).hide();
    $("#image1, #image3").slideUp('slow', function() {
      $("#image2").slideDown('slow');
    });
  });
  $("body").on('click', "#image3-thumbnail", function() {
    currentimage = "#image" + counter;
    counter = 3;
    $(currentimage).hide();
    $("#image1, #image2").fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $("#image3").fadeIn(1000);
    });
  });
  $("body").on('click', "#image1-thumbnail", function() {
    currentimage = "#image" + counter;
    counter = 1;
    $(currentimage).hide();
    $("#image2, #image3").fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $("#image1").fadeIn(1000);
    });
  });
  $("#rightArrow").click(function() {
    currentimage = "#image" + counter++;
    $(currentimage).hide();
    $("#image" + counter).show();
  })

  $("#lefttArrow").click(function() {
    currentimage = "#image2" + counter--;
    $(currentimage).hide();
    $("#image" + counter).show();
  })

});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightpink;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: yellow;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
}

#slideshow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#image1 {
  border-radius: 100px;
}

#image2 {
  border-radius: 100px;
}

#image3 {
  border-radius: 100px;
}

#image1-thumbnail {
  border-radius: 120px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#image2-thumbnail {
  border-radius: 120px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#image3-thumbnail {
  border-radius: 120px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#thumbnails {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  gap: 10px;
}

button {
  background-color: purple;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div id="header">
  <h1>Candy</h1>
</div>
<div id="slideshow">
  <img id="image1" src="https://wearenotmartha.com/wp-content/uploads/DIY-Rock-Candy-Featured.jpg" width="400px">
  <img id="image2" src="https://www.speachfamilycandy.com/contents/media/l_smallspicegumdrops.jpg" width="400px">
  <img id="image3" src="https://st4.depositphotos.com/4585465/20188/i/1600/depositphotos_201883238-stock-photo-colorful-candies-dessert-background.jpg" width="400px">
</div>
<div id="thumbnails">
  <button id="leftArrow"> &lt; </button>
  <img id="image1-thumbnail" src="https://wearenotmartha.com/wp-content/uploads/DIY-Rock-Candy-Featured.jpg" width="100px">
  <img id="image2-thumbnail" src="https://www.speachfamilycandy.com/contents/media/l_smallspicegumdrops.jpg" width="100px">
  <img id="image3-thumbnail" src="https://st4.depositphotos.com/4585465/20188/i/1600/depositphotos_201883238-stock-photo-colorful-candies-dessert-background.jpg" width="100px">
  <button id="rightArrow"> &gt; </button>
</div>
```

The primary issue in your code was you selector. You have, in a number of places:

```
currentimage = "#image2" + counter;
```

Your selector then becomes `#image21` initially. This selector does not select any items. So we change it to just:

```
currentimage = "#image" + counter;
```

This give us `#image1` initially.

Comment: I will try this thank you!

Comment: only issue I am having is it shows 2 images when I click on the thumbnails now when I use your first code and put it under my code   }); 
     $("body").on('click',"#image1-thumbnail",function() { 
        $("#image3").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#image2").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#image1").fadeIn(1000);    
     });

Comment: I put your code under that code to see if it would work but when I click thumbnails the right button works but the left button doesnt work correctly and when I click the thumbails it shows 2 images instead of one on some of them

Comment: I appreciate your help

Comment: @meg made some updates. I had some typos.

Comment: ok I am going to try the counter example because my professor insists I use that

Comment: Is there a way to do this with the counter but not with the index? she doesnt want me to use index she says it should be simpler than that

Comment: @meg there is always "a way" and now that I know it's for a class, many teachers will have you learn X then Y, so that Y is easier to understand, building upon X. Let me look back at the original code and see.

Comment: I figure it out but thank you for your help!